# Gallery with popup market style in app

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

Let me explain what I do.
On Android I want a gallery of images, possibly remotely (eg. from Market, or from another site), but with pop-ups that provide only a preview.
When someone taps it 's enlarges the image and goes to full screen.
To understand, how does the Android Market in the preview applications.

I tried to use the gallery of Android, but I could not only saved me without thumbnail images.

please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [scale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) down every image down to w * h and put all of them in a [list view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) adding [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to each entry that will bring up the image in full size

Comment: onTouchLister with an Intent?

Comment: If you want to, but it isn't required.